# Can my local MySQL server be accessed without permission

Tags: authentication, firewalls, mysql, authorization

I have hosted a MySQL database server on a VPS to connect to a flask web app on the same VPS. It only has users with host as local ip address. Can it be accessed by anyone else remotely, except me? If so, how can I make it more secure.

I don't know much about databases but I am scared if the information on my database can be accessed by anyone else.

The DB is hosted on a secure ec2 instance and there are no remote users just local ones.

Comment: By default MySQL listens for incoming connections on port 3306.  Being that your MySQL instance only accepts connections from local users, and not remote users, you might want to start by configuring iptables on your VM to block incoming connections to port 3306 from all outside IP addresses.

Comment: It is also related to the security of the EC2 instance in the first place. But It is not an excuse to not check the MySQL Database security.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on

1. Your MySQL version and method of installation. E.g. older versions of MySQL were often installed such a way you could connect to them remotely under the root account and do anything. Lastly what you believe is MySQL could be MariaDB or Percona.
2. Your firewall configuration.

It's impossible to answer this question generally. You need someone who understand all of this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how mysqld and the local network the host sits on has been configured.

A simple test to see if it is isolated would be to see if you can connect to port 3306 remotely. If you cannot, *and* you know you are using the correct IP address *and* that mysqld is using the default port, then you can be reasonably sure that other people on the internet cannot access the DB. OTOH other people using the same hosting *may* be able to connect.

In order to get to the data, access is usually restricted by a password or similar mechanism. Whether someone can get past this is a much more complex question.